# Understanding Java Heap memory using Profiler

Tags: java, heap-memory, profiler, analysis

When analysing heap dump using Eclipse MAT. I get the following statement.

> 25 instances of
>   "net.sf.ehcache.constructs.blocking.SelfPopulatingCache", loaded by
>   "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0x8be6f440" occupy 7,580,400
>   (21.37%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of
>   "java.util.concurrent.RunnableScheduledFuture[]", loaded by ""

I am unable to understand, what needs to be done.

The problem that I am facing with my standalone application is, it is using too much memory as shown by "System Monitor" in Ubuntu.

Please help.

Comment: Did you check the content of the this 25 Objects?, as far as i know ehcache can use a lot of memory depending on your configuration

Comment: But I haven't configured ehcache, so i suppose it has the default config.

Comment: Well that can be the cause xDD